# jsf 2 best one managed bean multiple views

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I`m kind of noob to JSF and I'm trying to figure out which would be the most elegant solution for the following scenario:
Let's say that I have a user managed bean called UserMB:

```
@ManagedBean
public class UserMB {

private User user;
private List<User> users;

// getters and setters here

public void addUser(User user){
    // do add user logic here
}


public List<User> listAllUsers(){
    // do list All users logic here
}


@PostConstruct
private void init(){

    // populate List<user> users - for the listAllUsers scenario

    }   
}
```

Let`s assume that i do not have a form to submit directly to listAllUsers() method, but instead i want to see all users when I open the page list-all-users.xhtml.
When I hit the managed bean from addUser.xhtml a query will be performed to DB to load all users because the bean will not know if i want to use listAllUsers() method or addUser() method.
Should i split this functionality in 2 managed beans ?

Because if so I would have to create several managed beans to deal with "User" business (ie. in Struts2 i would have only one Action that would take care of all user interactions).
P.S. I know that there is the solution to populate List  in getter method but I read one article of BalusC that advise us not to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Should i split this functionality in 2 managed beans ?*

Yes. Use one bean per view/form. Keep the backing bean class as slick as possible. Don't give it too much responsibilities.