# Can I use multiple managed bean in the same xhtml page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

when there are data that are repeated in several pages (reference example)
Is that I can load into a single managed bean and I use several managed bean in the same page.
What is its impact?

Comment: @freak IMO it will be better providing an answer or at least a better comment.

Comment: you need to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663861/jsf-2-best-one-managed-bean-multiple-views

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Can I use multiple managed bean in the same xhtml page?

Yes, you can, I highly recommend you to try it :).

> What is its impact?

This depends on the managed beans scopes. A good example is having a view to register a new address and shows the logged user info  at the top of the page, similar to Amazon site where you add a new shipping address.

In this case, you can have among three managed beans:

- A `@SessionScoped` bean that will show the logged user info. In case of amazon view, it shows only the first name.
- A `@ApplicationScoped` bean that will provide the data for Countries. This info doesn't change too often (at least that a new country is born every day =\).
- A `@ViewScoped` bean that will handle the request data, error messages and the registration.

A sample of the above explanation in Facelets code:

```html
<div id="top">
    Hello #{sessionBean.user.firstName}
</div>
<div id="body">
    <h1>Add an address</h1>
    <h:form id="frmAddress">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Address" />
            <h:inputText id="txtAddress" value="#{viewBean.address}" />
            <h:outputText value="Country" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="ddlCountry" value="#{viewBean.selectedCountry}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{applicationBean.countries}" var="country"
                    itemLabel="#{country.name}" itemValue="#{country}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:messages id="msgErrors" />
        <h:commandButton value="Save address" action="#{viewBean.saveAddress}" />
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Note: this is nor a good nor a bad practice, just give it a try to see how this behaves. The impact is defined how each managed bean behaves in the page, so it will be pretty neat or a really bad experience, based on how you have defined the beans.

Related info:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197)
- [Communication in JSF 2: Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)

Comment: Luiggi, that's a very nice answer.