# JSF multiple beans in one View, to get list of entities in db

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Ok, I've been discusing this with my colleages, and we can't find if what we are doing is ok or not, supose you have this view,

```
<h:form id="UsuarioEditForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="display" styleClass="createPanelGrid">
        <p:panelGrid  columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Nombre de Usuario: " for="nombreUsuario" />
            <p:inputText id="nombreUsuario" value="#{usuarioController.selected.nombreUsuario}" required="true" requiredMessage="Nombre requerido."/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Contraseña: " for="password" />
            <p:password id="password" value="#{usuarioController.selected.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Contraseña requerida."/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Correo Electrónico: " for="email" />
            <p:inputText id="email" value="#{usuarioController.selected.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Correo electrónico requerido."/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo de Usuario: " for="tipoUsuario" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="tipoUsuario" value="#{usuarioController.selected.tipoUsuario}" required="true" requiredMessage="Tipo de Usuario requerido." converter="#{tipoUsuarioConverter}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar..."/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{tipoUsuarioController.items}"
                 var="tipoUsuarioItem"  itemValue="#{tipoUsuarioItem}" itemLabel="#{tipoUsuarioItem.tipo}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:separator></p:separator>
        <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="#{usuarioController.save}" value="Guardar" update="display,:UsuarioListForm:datalist,:growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(xhr,status,args,UsuarioEditDialog);"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button" onclick="UsuarioEditDialog.hide()"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

the main managed bean who control the whole operation is called `usuarioController`, this bean do the logic to insert a `Usuario` entity, but, this entity needs a TipoUsuario entity for correct insert, so we have another bean called `tipoUsuarioController` that get the list of `TipoUsuario` entity and display it in a selectOneMenu where the user choose one `TipoUsuario`, so, the question is simple, it's ok to call a bean just to perform the operation to get the `TipoUsuario` List?, or it's better to get the List inside the `usuarioController` bean? Which operation is the best for the application performance?.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple managed bean in the same xhtml page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919545/can-i-use-multiple-managed-bean-in-the-same-xhtml-page). Refer to the country example in the answer.

Comment: ok, but lets say TipoUsuario is a list that can change a lot, if its applicationScoped bean, the list will change too? or I have to use ViewScoped to do the query again?

Comment: The fact that the `CountryBean` is `@ApplicationScoped` in my example doesn't mean it should be in your project/application as well. The scope of the bean is a totally different matter.

Comment: Anyway, IMO if your list needs to change, use a `@ViewScoped` for your `TipoUsuarioController`. If is not going to change until the application needs a redeploy or you have a strategy about changing its values and being reflected in the whole app, use `@ApplicationScoped`.

Comment: Precisely, thats my question, so its ok to have two `@ViewScoped` for example in the same xhtml page? in this case `UsuarioController` and `TipoUsuarioController` is this a good practice? and how about performance?

Comment: As you may see in my answer, you can have several beans in your page, regarding its scope. In my example I post three beans with different scope and it will work without problems. It is nor a good nor a bad practice, you just can do it and if it works for you, then do it. The only thing you should be aware is *how each managed bean behaves in the page,  so it will be pretty neat or a really bad experience, based on how you have defined the beans* (directly copied from my answer).

Comment: About performance, it will depend how you define the bean. IMO all the lists for dropdown components e.g. `<select>`s should be stored in `@ApplicationScope` or being in `@ViewScoped` but retrieved from cache or another mechanism that enhances the performance of your application. Note that this is more a design matter.

Comment: Got it, so its ok to have multiple `@ViewScoped` beans in the same xhtml page