# Why Backing Beans should be defined only in the request scope ?

Tags: jsf

I've been seraching about what's the difference between managed beans and backing beans and i've allready got the idea but i came through a website that mentioned this fact (or claim) for which i don't understand the reason : "Backing Beans should be defined only in the request scope". Is that even correct? If so ... why??

Answer (score 2):

There is [no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713483/difference-between-managed-bean-and-backing-bean) between the terms managed bean and backing bean in the context of JSF. The [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) tutorial uses them interchangeably.

You don't quote the website so there is no context to the author's generalization but request scope is often preferred to broader scopes for performance and concurrency reasons.

Comment: Just to add some info, is up to the developer/designer to decide the best scope for the managed bean, but this should be done having a good understanding of the scopes. There are two Q/As that explain this: [How to choose the right bean scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885/1065197) and [Can I use multiple managed bean in the same xhtml page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18919545/1065197).